# Recurrence relation: T(n) = T(n - 1) + n - 1

Tags: recurrence

I am trying to understand how to solve recurrence relations. I understand it to the point where we have to simplify.

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + N-1              Initial condition: T(1)=O(1)=1
T(N) = T(N-1) + N-1
T(N-1) = T(N-2) + N-2
T(N-2) = T(N-3) + N-3
……
T(2) = T(1) + 1


**Summing up right and left sides**

T(N) + T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3) + …. T(3) + T(2) =

= T(N-1) + T(N-2) + T(N-3) + …. T(3) + T(2) + T(1) +

(N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + …. +3 + 2 + 1


** Canceling like terms and simplifying **

T(N) = T(1) + N*(N-1)/2 1 + N*(N - 1)/2

T(N) = 1 + N*(N - 1)/2
```

I really don't understand the last part. I understand canceling like terms but don't understand how the simplification below works:

```
T(N) = T(1) + (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + …. +3 + 2 + 1
T(N) = T(1) + N*(N-1)/2 1 + N*(N - 1)/2
```

How is the second line derived from the first? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Would be a great help if someone can help me understand this. Thanks =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve: T(n) = T(n - 1) + n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752977/how-to-solve-tn-tn-1-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second-to-last-line:

```
 S = (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1
```

You can say:

```
2S = S + S
   = (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... +   3   +   2   +   1
       1   +   2   +   3   + ... + (N-3) + (N-2) + (N-1)
   =   N   +   N   +   N   + ... +   N   +   N   +   N
       |__________________ N-1 times ________________|
```

You're counting from `N - 1` to `1`, so there are `N - 1` terms in the sequence. But the whole sequence is just `N` so you can say:

```
2S = N * (N - 1)
 S = (N * (N - 1)) / 2
```

So in your last chunk:

```
T(N) = T(1) + (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1
     = T(1) + (N * (N - 1)) / 2
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. Where does the '2S = S + S' come from?

Comment: `2S = S + S`? `2 = 1 + 1`. It's just a true statement. Proving things isn't as intuitive as reading through the proof, so this is one of those examples that you just have to look at and accept. It's a trick that simplifies things.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(N) = T(1) + (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + …. +3 + 2 + 1
     = T(1) + (N-1) +  (N-2) + (N-3) + ..... + ( N-(N-3)) + (N-(N-2)) + (N-(N-1))
     = T(1) + [N+N+N+..... n-1 times] - [1+2+3+......+(N-3)+(N-2)+(N-1)]
     = T(1) + N*(N-1) - (N*(N-1))/2
     = T(1) + N*(N-1)/2
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I kind of get it. Don't understand why we divide by 2 ? :S

Comment: @HarryTiron divide by 2 is actually the part of n*(n+1)/2 which is sum of n natural numbers, here we have to find sum of (n-1)natural numbers i.e. 1+2+3+....+(n-1). so sum is (n-1)*(n-1+1)/2. see this wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_natural_numbers