# Understanding recurrence relation

Tags: iteration, recurrence

I have this recurrence relation

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n, for n ≥ 2
T(1) = 1
```

Practice exercise: Solve recurrence relation using the iteration method and give an asymptotic running time.

So I solved it like this:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n 
        = T(n-2)  + (n - 1) + n 
        = T(n-3) + (n - 2) + (n - 1) + n 
        = … 
        = T(1) + 2 + … (n - 2) + (n - 1) + n **
        = 1 + 2 + … + (n - 2) + (n - 1) + n
        = O(n^2)
```

I have some questions:

> 1)How I can find asymptotic running time?
>
> **2)At this state of problem T(1) means that there was n that when it was subtracted with a number it gave the result 1, right?
>
> 3)What if T(0) = 1 and what if T(2) = 1?

Edit: 4) Why `n ≥ 2` is useful?

I need really to understand it for my Mid-Term test

Comment: you have already done #1

Comment: #3: the asymptotic running time doesn't change in this case.

Comment: So if I done the first one that mean that I didnt solve the recurrence relation? How to solve it?

Comment: #1, #2: `T(x)` represents the running time, not the computation result

Comment: If you want the time needed to compute `T`, now that's another (and quite easy) question.

Comment: The time needed to compute `T` is linear using the recursive relation, constant using a closed form. If we don't assume constant time math operations, then the time to compute `T` is quadratic using the recursive relation.

Comment: Jan Dvorak you should add one answer so i could give you best answer... its quite difficult to read its like this... Can you gather all your thoughts and write it as one answer?

Comment: I still didn't understand why I need `n ≥ 2` and if by writing the solution that I wrote answer the question of exercise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve: T(n) = T(n - 1) + n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752977/how-to-solve-tn-tn-1-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n, for n ≥ 2
T(1) = 1
```

If `T(x)` represents the running time:

You have already found the asymptotic running time, `O(n^2)` (quadratic).

If the relation is changed to `T(0) = 1` or `T(2) = 1`, then the running time is still quadratic. The asymptotic behavior does not change if you add a constant or multiply by a constant, and changing the initial condition only adds a constant to the following terms.

`n ≥ 2` is present in the relation so that `T(n)` is defined at exactly once for every positive `n`. Otherwise, both lines would apply to `T(1)`. You cannot compute `T(1)` from `T(0)` using `T(n) = T(n-1) + n`. Even if you could, `T(1)` would be defined in two different (and potentially inconsistent) ways.

Comment: Pff I still doesn't understand the `n ≥ 2`... So my solution answer to all exercise questions?

Comment: ad `n ≥ 2` how would you compute `T(n)` if `n ≥ 2` was not present? The human can see what's the base case, but technically both lines would _define_ `T(1)`, but you cannot compute `T(1)` from `T(1) = T(0) + 1`