# Master Theorem and substitution method on (n-1)

Tags: math, substitution, recurrence, master-theorem

Which method should I use to solve this recurrence ?

```
 T(n)= {  Θ(1)             if n = 1
       {  T(n-1) + Θ(n)    if n > 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve: T(n) = T(n - 1) + n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752977/how-to-solve-tn-tn-1-n)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using the iteration method. As a hint, it solves to Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using the master mathod and we can find that:

a = 1, b = 1 and d = 1, then a = b^d.

So T(n) = (number of levels) * (work per level) = n * n