# Solving a Recurrence Relation: T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I have been asked to solve that recurrence relation. I got the next solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUmA.jpg

So I decided to ask my teacher if it was right. He told me that it wasn't; and that this is the right solution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhyKL.jpg

I'm totally clueless right now. The most I try to understand why mine is wrong; the most I think it's actually right.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Comment: You should ask to close this one as well @RaymondChen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752977/how-to-solve-tn-tn-1-n

Comment: The second solution seems incorrect to me, specially because for a large value of n it would be negative.

Comment: @xFunkyTimes Done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Here's a different approach with the same result:

```
t(1) = 0 (given)
t(2) = t(1) + 1 = 1
t(3) = t(2) + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3
t(4) = t(3) + 3 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
...
t(n) = 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1) = n * (n - 1) / 2 = Theta(n^2).
```

The teacher's solution is wrong after the second `=` sign. Here's what the teacher wrote:

```
t(n-1) + n - 1 = t(n-2) + n - 1 - 2
```

But actually the following is correct:

```
t(n-1) + n - 1 = ( t(n-2) + n - 2 ) + n - 1
```

which is actually exactly what you got. It appears that the teacher dropped an `n` term.

In fact, the teacher's solution ends with a dominant term of `-n^2` which is clearly wrong, as `t(n) >= 0` for all `n >= 0`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot @pkpnd