# What is the time complexity of a recursive algorithm given by the recurrence T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am completely new to this so a step by stem would help greatly, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve: T(n) = T(n - 1) + n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752977/how-to-solve-tn-tn-1-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can start with [iteration method](https://www.codesdope.com/course/algorithms-lets-iterate/) to understand how this behaves.

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1 = 
     = 2*(2T(n-2) + 1) + 1 = 4T(n-2) + 3
     = 4(2T(n-3) + 1) + 3 = 8T(n-3) + 7
     = 8*(2T(n-4) + 1) + 7 = 16T(n-4) + 15
     = 16*(2T(n-5) + 1) + 15 = 32T(n-5) + 31
```

Now, that we understand the behavior, we can tell

```
T(n) = 2^i * T(n-i) + (2^i - 1)
```

Now, we need to use the base clause (which is not given in question), and extract for `i=n`. For example, if `T(0) = 0`:

```
T(n) = 2^n * T(0) + (2^n - 1) = 2^n - 1
```

This is in `O(2^n)`, when calculating asymptotic complexity.

**Note:** Iteration method is good and easy to follow - but it is not a formal proof. To formally prove the complexity, you are going to need another tool, such as induction.

Comment: Thank you so much!